# Can C++ be called from C# compiled to wasm?

Tags: c#, c++, webassembly, uno-platform

Does anyone know if it's currently possible to call C++ from C# compiled to wasm (or an Uno Platform app to be more precise)?

I'm fairly new to WebAssembly but I managed to compile a C++ function to wasm and call it from JavaScript.
I also got the quick start project from Uno (which allows you to compile UWP apps written in C#/XAML to wasm and run them in the browser) running.

I write both C# and C++ on a daily basis, but what I can't figure out is the "interopping between 2 languages" + WebAssembly combo.
I assume I need to compile the code in both languages to 2 separate wasm files and then somehow link them together or load the C++ one at runtime.
Is what I want to do even possible at all today?

EDIT: To be clear: the idea is that all code is eventually compiled to wasm.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2019) might be useful.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I don't think that's going to work. I don't really have a native dll: my C++ should also be wasm and run cross platform in the browser. And even if it would be a native dll then I doubt PInvoking is going to work, it's not the good old CLR afterall.

Comment: Ok @OrkhanAlikhanov, PInvoke does seem to be the way to go, but needs to be properly set up in the project first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

P/Invoke is supported since last month by the mono-wasm runtime, using two modes:

- [Dynamic linking](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking) of an arbitrary WebAssembly module, when running with the mono interpreter
- Static linking of LLVM bitcode files generated by prior emscripten invocations, when running under mono's AOT

The latter is being worked on at the moment in the Uno.Wasm.Bootstrapper [in this PR](https://github.com/nventive/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/pull/94).

It has the exact same behavior another .NET runtime may have, which means that C++ cannot be access directly, and you'll have to expose a C API to be able to use it.

There are some caveats with the use of C++, where the runtime needs to be forcibly included in the mono runtime's binaries, making it larger. This may change soon, since emscripten is moving to a full LLVM backend.

Some documentation is for the Uno.Wasm.Bootstrapper is [available here](https://github.com/nventive/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#webassembly-module-linking-support).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for!